# How to avoid the external changes?

Tags: c#

For example, I have a class

```
class Car
{
    Engine TheEngine {get; set;}
}
```

And when I set the engine

```
Engine engine = new Engine();
Car.TheEngine = engine;
```

And if I change engine

```
engine.Change();
```

Then Car.TheEngine is also changed. How to get a better design to avoid the side-effect?

Comment: design your classes to be as immutable as possible

Comment: Don't have a `Change` method that changes the `Engine`. As an alternative, have a `Change` method that performs the change on a copy and returns the copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expose a mutator method, then by definition the instance can be mutated. To achieve what you want, make all such methods return a new instance instead.

So, this:

```
public void Change()
{
    this.PropertyB++;
}
```

Should be changed to look like this:

```
public Engine Change()
{
    return new Engine
    { 
        PropertyA = this.PropertyA,
        PropertyB = this.PropertyB + 1,
        PropertyC = this.PropertyC,
    };
}
```